# jme3 - Exported blender model throws "Num components must be between 1 and 4"

Tags: java, model, 3d, blender, jmonkeyengine

I created a [model of a robot](http://bit.ly/1eV1U9x) which has an armature and two animation actions in it, “walk” and “stand”. I exported this model with the latest blender2ogre exporter plugin (my Blender version is 2.69, plugin version is 0.6.0) like this:

1: Select the armature of my model:

[image: The selected armature]

2: Export it with the ogre plugin with these settings:

[image: Ogre export plugin settings]

3: Result are the files “Robobob.mesh.xml” and “Robobob.skeleton.xml” (no errors).

I added both to my assets, now when loading my model with the Asset-Manager, I get this exception:

```
SEVERE: Uncaught exception thrown in Thread[LWJGL Renderer Thread,5,main]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Num components must be between 1 and 4
at com.jme3.scene.VertexBuffer.createBuffer(VertexBuffer.java:907)
at com.jme3.scene.Mesh.extractVertexData(Mesh.java:1176)
at com.jme3.scene.plugins.ogre.MeshLoader.compileModel(MeshLoader.java:776)
at com.jme3.scene.plugins.ogre.MeshLoader.load(MeshLoader.java:892)
at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadAsset(DesktopAssetManager.java:288)
at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadModel(DesktopAssetManager.java:374)
at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadModel(DesktopAssetManager.java:378)
at de.my.game.MyGame.makePlayer(MyGame.java:59)
at de.my.game.MyGame.simpleInitApp(MyGame.java:43)
at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:226)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is this the right way of exporting and does anyone have an idea whats wrong with my model?

Thanks in advance! :)